# How to add latest tag to docker images and handle updates?

Tags: docker, docker-image

When we create a docker image we can tag the image using `-t` argument.
`docker build  -t my-image-name:latest`

But I keep updating the image. So the new image will become latest and previous image will be old. But two images cannot have the same `latest` tag. How do we solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a versioning strategy like semantic versioning to tag images?
You can use a version like v1.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

We apply a couple (or more) tags while building an image:
`docker build -t my-image:1.0 -t my-image:latest`

In new version we use the same technique:
`docker biuld -t my-image:1.1 -t my-image:latest`

As far as i know it works exactly this way - `latest` tag does float between images.

Docs for [docker build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#tag-image-t) command.
You can create a [new tag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/) explicitly referring to specific image.

Cheers!